# Android ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, error-handling

I'm struggeling with this error that I can't understand. Could anyone help me out here?

```
07-29 20:05:26.113: E/ActivityManager(339): ANR in com.coderogden.pongtennis 
(com.coderogden.pongtennis/.activities.StartLvlActivity)
07-29 20:05:26.113: E/ActivityManager(339): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
```

Comment: This is caused by you doing something expensive on the UI thread and a keyevent comes in that can't be handled.  Try moving any method that you think could be expensive to a background thread.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your quick respons! However, I'm new to Android programming and I'm not completely sure what you mean, but at the same time I do. My UI thread seems slightly overloaded as it doesn't draw all the graphics I've implemented in the thread. But what kind of graphics can I remove, and how do I set up a background thread? Thanks in advance! // CoderOgden